# Specifying different lists

Tags: c#

I'm recently trying to compare and specify the different lists in C#.
for instance,

```
List <int> list1 = new List<int>{3,1,2,0};
List <int> list2 = new List<int>{2,3,5,1};
List <int> list3 = new List<int>{0,1,3,2};
List <int> list4 = new List<int>{0,1,3,2}; 

//I want to get  {3,1,2,0} , {2,3,5,1} , {0,1,3,2} those three types.
```

I got 4 lists, list3 equals to list4, list1 and list2 are different. 
Although the content in list1, list3, and list4 are the same, the orders are different so it doesn't count. Eventually, it should return only three distinct lists. ({3,1,2,0} , {2,3,5,1} , {0,1,3,2})

Thank you so much!

Comment: What did you try so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: That describes what you want, but not describes how you are trying to get it and what problem you faced. Please update your question with these details.

Answer (score 5):

The results that you are seeing are correct, you have 4 different lists, 2 of which happen to have the same content.

Technically you have 4 references 2 lists, and `list3` and `list4` are references to 2 different lists that happent to have the same content.

If you need to check that the content of the lists is the same then I would suggest the linq `SequenceEqual` function.

---

To generate the output you're looking for I would suggest, that you combine `Distinct()` with `SequenceEqual()`. However, there are a number of pitfalls here:

- `SequenceEqual()` and `Distinct()` are both optimised, but I would be wary of this for long lists.
- The current implementation of `Distinct()` has a dependency on `GetHashCode()` so you need to be careful here too.

I've added a simple example below, but it comes with a massive warning label.

If you're planning to use this with a decent size list, the implementation of ListValueComparer.GetHashCode() becomes critical. Like all `GetHashCode()` implemenations, it needs to:

- be fast,
- return the same result for the same input
- return reasonably diffrent results for different inputs.

If it doesn't meet all 3 criteria you will be in a world of hurt!

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
using System.Linq;

namespace list_compare
{
    class ListValueComparer : IEqualityComparer<List<int>>
    {
        public bool Equals([AllowNull] List<int> x, [AllowNull] List<int> y)
        {
            if (x == null || y == null)
                return false;

            return x.SequenceEqual(y);
        }

        public int GetHashCode([DisallowNull] List<int> obj)
        {
            return obj.Aggregate((a, b) => a ^ b);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var lists = new List<List<int>>{
                new List<int>{3,1,2,0},
                new List<int>{2,3,5,1},
                new List<int>{0,1,3,2},
                new List<int>{0,1,3,2}
            };

            var distinct = lists
                .Distinct(new ListValueComparer())
                .ToList();

            foreach (var list in distinct)
            {
                foreach (var item in list)
                {
                    Console.Write(item.ToString());
                    Console.Write(" ");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which gives the output

```
3 1 2 0 
2 3 5 1 
0 1 3 2
```